# How to make an arbitrary application trust my SSL certificate?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, capture, mitmproxy

I have installed charles (or any other mitm proxy), installed its certificate as root CA, run proxy 127.0.0.1:8889.

However, simple requests.get ('https://stackoverflow.com/') in python does not work, it gives an error *certificate verify failed*. The charles documentation suggests source code forcing to trust the certificate. session.verify = "charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem". Likewise with browsers, instructions are on https: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

But what if I want to see https traffic of arbitrary .exe? I don’t have access to its sources, and it doesn’t provide any means for importing certificates (like browsers).

Comment: Have you tried to install the fake certificate as root certificate on the underlying operating system ?

Comment: Yes, i did. But application still not trust. I used charles with proxifier

Answer (score 0):

It seems that any application has is own trusted store and python seems to not be an exception.

Try this approach from your Python code:

> So in python also we get an error for such a self-signed certificate. We can fix the same by passing the certificate
>
> > > > req = urlopen("https://dev.tarunlalwani.com/testme", cafile="/vagrant/certs/selfsigned.crt")
> > > >         req.read()
> > > >         'GET /testme \n'

Source: http://tarunlalwani.com/post/self-signed-certificates-trusting-them/

The above link also have instructions how to trust your self signed certificate in more applications and in several operating systems.

Some Context:

At work we use Ubuntu and we are behind a firewall that decrypts and inspects all https traffic and encrypts it again to send it back to the wire, thus we use custom self signed certificates and this made me discover that I need to add the self signed certificate to any application I work with.